# System.InvalidCastException Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I can't figure out why i kept getting the error even when my detailsview is done correctly. 
Variables have been declared beforehand and most of the classes are correct.
I'm doing a e-commerce website using visual C# for a school module.

```
    //extract the QuantityOnHand from the database - based on the product ID
    strSQLSelect = "SELECT pQuantity FROM Product WHERE pProdNo = @ProductID";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strProductId;
    object oQty = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    intQuantityOnHand = (int)oQty; //error here
```

Advise and help will be greatly appreciated!

Entire Coding for the page below:

```
static readonly string scriptStockOut = "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
"alert (\"Sorry Stock Out!  Please choose a smaller quantity or another product \");\n" +
"</script>";

static readonly string scriptErrorLogin = "<script language=\"javascript\">\n" +
   "alert (\"Please login or create account first to facilitate buying\");\n</script>";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //declare variables
    string strProductId, strSQLSelect, strSQL;
    int intQuantityOnHand, intBuyQuantity, newQty, intOrderNo;
    decimal decUnitPrice;


    // test to remind customer to login first
    if ((string)Session["sFlag"] != "T")
    {
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorLogin);
    }

    // connect to database and then check stock quantity
    OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
    mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
         + Server.MapPath("~/Database.accdb");
    mDB.Open(); OleDbCommand cmd;

    //retrieve the product ID from the first row of the DetailsView
    DetailsViewRow row0 = DetailsView1.Rows[0];
    strProductId = row0.Cells[1].Text;

    //extract the QuantityOnHand from the database - based on the product ID
    strSQLSelect = "SELECT pQuantity FROM Product WHERE pProdNo = @ProductID";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strProductId;
    object oQty = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    intQuantityOnHand = (int)oQty;

    //extract the Promotion Price from the database - based on the product ID
    strSQLSelect = "SELECT pPromoCost FROM Product WHERE pProdNo = @ProductID";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQLSelect, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strProductId;
    object oUnitPrice = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    decUnitPrice = (decimal)oUnitPrice;

    //extract the quantity purchased from the dropdown list
    intBuyQuantity = int.Parse(ddlQty.Items[ddlQty.SelectedIndex].ToString());

    //calculate the new quantity left
    newQty = intQuantityOnHand - intBuyQuantity;

    //checking for out of stock situation
    if (intQuantityOnHand < intBuyQuantity)
    {
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "StockOut", scriptStockOut);
    }

    // save productID, unitPrice and quantity as Session variables
    Session["sProductId"] = strProductId;
    Session["sUnitPrice"] = decUnitPrice.ToString();
    Session["sQuantity"] = newQty.ToString();

    // insert product ordered to the orderItems table
    intOrderNo = (int)Session["sOrderNo"];
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO InvoiceDetails(idOrderNo, idProdID, idQty, idUnitPrice)"
         + "VALUES (@OrderNo, @ProductId, @Qty, @UnitPrice)";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OrderNO", OleDbType.Integer).Value = intOrderNo;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strProductId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Qty", OleDbType.Integer).Value = intBuyQuantity;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = decUnitPrice;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //update the quantity on hand in the products table
    strSQL = "UPDATE Product SET pQuantity = @NewQty WHERE pProdNo = @ProductId";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = newQty;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewQty", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strProductId;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    mDB.Close();

    // redirect the user to the Shopping Cart page
    Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");

}
```

}

Comment: is `oQty` `Nullable`?

Comment: What is the type of `pQuantity` in the database?

Comment: The type is 'Number'

Comment: Well, that's simple: `oQty` is **not** an `int` - try `long`, or just call `oQty.GetType()` to know the type.

Comment: What is the database type that you are using?

Comment: Microsoft Access.
And I do not think it's nullable..

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552970/to-which-c-sharp-data-type-does-ms-access-number-type-correspond